# How can new activity get data image from recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I want to send data from RecyclerView to Activity, but *Image Data* from Arraylist in RecyclerView isn't sent to Activity.

I was successful to compile the code, but whenever I open the app and select 1 item in Recycleriew, the app gets force closed.

I expect the image and description data display in Activity, but the app is always forced close.

**Fragment Class**:

```
public class ShipFragment extends Fragment {

    private View v;
    private RecyclerView recyclerShip;
    private ArrayList<Warship> shipList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ship_fragment, container,false);

        recyclerShip = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.Recycler_id);
        shipList.addAll(ShipDataRecycler.getShipList());
        recyclerShip.setHasFixedSize(true);
        showRecyclerShipList();

        return v;
    }

    private void showRecyclerShipList() {
        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(shipList);
        recyclerShip.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerShip.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        recyclerAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(new RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Warship zListShip) {
                showSelectedShip(zListShip);
            }
        });
    }
    private void showSelectedShip(Warship ship){
        Intent swap = new Intent(getActivity(), Detail_item.class);
        swap.putExtra(Detail_item.image,ship.getImges());
        swap.putExtra(Detail_item.title, ship.getzTitle());
        swap.putExtra(Detail_item.description, ship.getzDescription());
        startActivity(swap);
    }
}
```

**Activity Class**:

```
public class Detail_item extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imgDetail;
    private TextView titleDetail, descDetail;
    private ArrayList<Warship> listWarship;
    public static final String title = "Nama";
    public static final String description = "deskripsi";
    public static final String image = "foto";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_item);

        imgDetail = findViewById(R.id.profil_img_id);
        titleDetail = findViewById(R.id.titleShip_id);
        descDetail = findViewById(R.id.desc_id);

        String imageShip = getIntent().getStringExtra(image);
        String titleShip = getIntent().getStringExtra(title);
        String descShip = getIntent().getStringExtra(description);

        titleDetail.setText(titleShip);
        imgDetail.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imageShip));
        descDetail.setText(descShip);
    }
}
```

**Crash Logs** :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.kimino.azurlaneshipreview/com.kimino.azurlaneshipreview.Detail_item}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:483)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
>           at com.kimino.azurlaneshipreview.Detail_item.onCreate(Detail_item.java:38)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6864)
>           at >android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)         >at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)

Comment: what does `ship.getImges()` return?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because

`String imageShip = getIntent().getStringExtra(image);`

is returning a null value. When you run `Integer.parseInt(imageShip)`, you get the `NullFormatException`.

You should make sure that you are assigning

`public static final String image = "foto";`

as the key when you assign the extra value,

```
//make sure that Detail_item.image == "foto" or that when you get the 
//extra, you are using the same key.
swap.putExtra(Detail_item.image,ship.getImges());
```

Currently that request is returning `null`.